# Android studio fails to build any app suddenly

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

My android studio suddenly stopped building apps it was working fine before but now i cant even run the basic empty application.

Syncing and all is working fine no errors there but the error is displayed only when i sideload(run) apps or generate signed apk

ALready tried

1. Invalidate Cache / Restart
2. Restarting
3. Changing java version
4. Cleaning all files

Nothing worked

[image: Error List]

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.alpha.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
}
```

build.gradel:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you migrate to AndroidX or what was your last app level Gradle action?

Comment: Post `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle`

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException added

Comment: @TaseerAhmad yes i migrated to androidX

Comment: You need to start using `androidx` imports, manually refactor your code.

Comment: @rohanparab Does my answer... Work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this block of code:

```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
        implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    }
```

Based on this you haven't [fully migrated to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

If you are looking for copy/paste with the correct dependencies, replace the dependency block with:

```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    }
```

Also in the `defaultConfig` block change the `testInstrumentationRunner`. Then change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` from 28 to 29.

**Old**

```
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.alpha.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

**New**

```
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.alpha.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```